# How to trigger automatic build in gitlab CI on commit to non-default branch?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a project in GitLab that is integrated with Gitlab CI. Every push to master shedules a build of the project.

However, when a new branch is created and pushed into repository, build is not sheduled in gitlab CI. What are the settings for enabling build of other branches - alterativaly, how can i figure out what went wrong?

Comment: at the project settings inside ci you can configure: "Make tabs for the following branches". that sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i figure out what went wrong?

Analyse `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60946693/10950272), I would take a wild guess that you have limited your job execution with:

```yaml
...
  only:
    - master
...
```