# GITLAB CI Pipeline not triggered

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

I have written this yml file for GitLab CI/CD. There is a shared runner configured and running.
I am doing this first time and not sure where I am going wrong. The angular js project I am having
on the repo has a gulp build file and works perfectly on local machine. This code just has to trigger
that on the vm where my runner is present. On commit the pipeline does not show any job. Let me know what needs to be corrected!

```yaml
image: docker:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

deploy_stage:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  environment: stage
  script:
  - rmdir -rf "build"
  - mkdir "build"
  - cd "build"
  - git init
  - git clone "my url"
  - cd "path of cloned repository"
  - gulp build
```

Answer (score 10):

What branch are you commiting to? You pipeline is configured to run only for commit on `master` branch.

```yaml
...
  only:
    - master
...
```

If you want to have triggered jobs for other branches as well then remove this restriction from `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Do not forget to `Enable shared Runners` (they may not be enabled by default), setting can be found on GitLab project page under `Settings -> CI/CD -> Runners`.

Update: Did your pipeline triggers ever work for your project?

If not then I would try configuring simple pipeline just to test if triggers work fine:

```yaml
test_simple_job:
  script:
    - echo I should execute for any pipeline trigger.
```

Comment: I am committing to master branch, shared runners are enabled as well.

Comment: Did your pipeline ever work for this project? How about you commit some simple pipeline just to test if jobs are triggered properly for your project (example pipeline in updated answer).

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by renaming the .gitlab-ci.yaml to .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: Why was it named `.gitlab-ci.yaml` in the first place?

Comment: gitlab pipelines are written in this file and .yml and .yaml are interchangable

Comment: I know that the extensions are intechangeable. That's not what I asked. :) What I wanted to know is *why did you have .yaml instead of .yml for this file, how did it happen*.

Comment: @EricAya , manually create the file in the text editor with the wrong name, copy past the content from another project with a working pipeline. Happens once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://status.gitlab.com for runners services. I had a case when service malfunction were preventing me from running my private runner. You need to wait till all statuses will get back to normal ("Operational" on the language of gitlab)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I ran into a similar issue. I was committing my code and I was not seeing the pipeline trigger at all.There was also no error statement on gitlab nor in my vscode. It had ran perfectly before.My problem was because I had made some recent edits to my yaml that were invalid.I reverted the changes to a known valid yaml code, and it worked again and passed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. I thought I would document the cause, in the hopes it may help someone (although this is not strictly an answer for the original question because my deploy script is more complex).

So in my case, the reason was that I had multiple jobs with the same job ID in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`. The latter one basically rendered the earlier one invisible.

```yaml
# This job will never run:
deploy_my_stuff:
  script:
    - do something for job one

# This job overwrites the above.
deploy_my_stuff:
  script:
    - do something for job two
```

Totally obvious... after I discovered the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file directly on the GitLab *web page* and it was not working. The pipeline was never triggered.

I cloned the code locally, removed the `yml` file and committed. After adding the file again I committed again and pushed and it worked.